# virtual function doubts c++

Tags: c++, function, virtual

Virtual function `d()` in the base class `A` is overidden by a private method in derived class `B`. When `d()` is invoked on an instance of `B` from outside, via a pointer of type `A *`, it is `B::d()` that runs, even though it is private to `B`.

Why does this happen?  Shouldn't it be impossible for code outside `B` to invoke `B`'s private methods?

### Demo

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
  virtual void d(){
    cout<<" gfgd ";
  }
};

class B :
  public A
  {
    private:
    void d(){
        cout<<"hytyhtht";
    }
  };

  int main() {
    A *a1;
    B b;
    a1=&b;
    a1->d();
    return 0;
  }
```

**Output:**

> hytyhtht

Comment: It seems like a mistake to begin with, that a non-private method can be overridden by a private method. That's a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle, that each subclass's object should be substitutable for its superclass'

Answer (score 2):

The public/protected/private access-rules are enforced at compile-time, not at run-time, which means that they have to rely on logic that the compiler can enforce at compile-time.

In particular, the compiler knows that you are calling the `d()` method using a `A*` pointer, and that class `A` has declared `virtual void d()` to be a public method, so that means it's okay to call the method.

In general the compiler can't know at compile-time that your pointer is really pointing to a `B` object, so even if it wanted to it wouldn't be able to flag the call as a compile-time error.  (Well, maybe in your particular example it could, but in many cases the compiler doesn't know what the type of the pointer-to object will be, it only knows the type of the pointer)

For example:

```
// in someotherfile.cpp
void MyFunction(A * a)
{
   a->d();  // should this compile, or not?
}
```